# How to pull all Int vals out of List[Any]?

Tags: scala

I have a List[Any] in Scala which contains a mix of Int, String, Char, and List. I want to pull out only the Int values into a new List that would be List[Int]. How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the method `collect`, which is like a combination of `map` and `filter` with a partial function as its parameter.

`List(1, 2, "Foo", 39.7 ).collect{ case i: Int => i }`

The result is `List(1, 2)`, and the compiler knows that the type is List[Int] rather than List[Any].